# What will be result of code execution? C Operator Precedence

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I have a problem with predicting result of code linked below.
Why program is printing `2 0 6 0 10 0 16 0 20 0` ? I guess it is all about operators precedence, but after thinking a while I can't realize what's wrong with my interpretation. Can you explain it a little bit?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int tab[10] = {2,4,6,8,10,14,16,18,20};
    int *pi, i;
    for(pi = tab; ++pi < tab+9;)
    {
        *pi++ = 0;
        *pi *= 2;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%d ", tab[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I can't realize what's wrong with my interpretation" - what's your interpretation?

Comment: where in that code you have a doubt ? if it is `++pi < tab+9`, it is like `((++i) < (tab + 9))`

Comment: I don't understand why **pi** pointer firstly points at tab[1], then at tab[2]

Comment: I can't reproduce your output. [Demo on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/UUy8QO)

Comment: step through each line of code in a debugger.

Comment: @dannyxn what else do you expect and why?

Comment: @dannyxn _pi_ point first to _tab_, the form `*pi++ = 0;` is like `*pi = 0; pi += 1;`. `++pi` return the value after the increment while `pi++` return the value of _pî_ then increment it

Comment: Postfix operators bind more tightly than prefix operators. So `*p++` is the same as `*(p++)`. I don't know if that is your confusion, but it's the only case of operator precedence in that snippet.

Comment: What output were you expecting to see, and why?

Comment: I thought that firstly **pi** is preincremented to **pi+1**, then post incremented to **pi+2**

Comment: That is why the second number is `0` and the third gets doubled.

Comment: As **pi=tab** points at tab[0] then *pi++ shouldn't point to tab[2]?

Comment: The very first time the loop is executed, `pi` points to `tab[1]` because of the `++pi < tab+9` end condition. Also please [edit]  your question and tell us what output you expect. Best don't write weird code like this.

Comment: To answer this kind of question I suggest you to use debug.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It's from my university C exam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that the `for` loop does is point `pi` at `tab`, i.e. `pi=&tab[0]`
So `pi` is pointing at the number 2. The next piece of code to be executed is the `for` loop's "condition" statement `++pi < tab+9`. This first increments `pi` (so it's now pointing at the number 4 in `tab[1]`) and checks whether it's still pointing at a member of `tab` earlier than the final 20.

In the body of the `for` loop, the line `*pi++ = 0;` first stores a 0 at the address pointed to by `pi` (which means that `tab[1]` is now 0 rather than 4) and then (post-) increments `pi` to point at `tab[2]`, which is 6. Then the line `*pi *= 2;` doubles the value pointed to by `pi`, so `tab[2]` becomes 12.

The next thing that happens is a re-evaluation of the `for` loop's conditional statement (since its iteration statement is empty): `pi` is incremented and checked.

The rest of the iterations are fairly uneventful. The final state of `tab` is that the first member is unchanged, members with an odd index are zero, and other members are doubled from their initial value.

General advice regarding operators and precedence: one of two situations is almost always the case. The first is that you and the compiler don't agree on the order in which the operators in your code will be applied—in other words your code doesn't do what you expect. The second is that you understand perfectly what the compiler is going to do, but the programmer reading your code does not—in other words your code doesn't do what *they* expect. Fortunately, both situations can be mitigated by adding parentheses to remove any doubt.

Answer (score 1):

The actual output is `2 0 12 0 20 0 32 0 40 0` (as shown in Blastfurnace comment https://ideone.com/UUy8QO)

`pi` is indeed initially on the first cell, but your stop condition increment the pointer. Therefore, inside the loop, for the first instruction, `pi` is in `tab[1]`. It first put this cell to 0, then increment with ++. On the second line, it double the value, therefore it double `tab[2]`. Then, the stop condition again increment the pointer, and so on.